# Prove that $H_f(x_0, y_0) = 0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f : Ω ⊆ \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function of class $C^{2}(Ω)$ and $(x_0, y_0)$ a local minimum of $f$ such that $∆f(x_0, y_0) = 0$. Prove that $H_f(x_0, y_0) = 0$.

How can I use the Laplacian operator $∆f$ to prove this? Or is there another way?

Comment: Think of the Hessian as a matrix. How many entries are there? What does $\Delta f(x_0,y_0)$ tell you about the entries? Do you know the second-derivative test for classifying critical points? (if yes, what does that tell you about the remaining entries? If no, look it up).

Comment: If the Hessian has entries $(a,b,c,d)$ then at the critical point you have $f(x,y)=ax^2+(b+c)xy+dy^2+u(x,y)$ where $u$ is a residue that goes to zero faster than the norm of $(x,y)$ squared. Essentially, the Hessian is a parabola and this dominates the function near the critical value. The hypothesis yields $a+d=0.$ Can you play with these quantities anc conclude?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you

Comment: @WilliamM. Thank you, I’ll try